# Java: How to convert a String of Binary values to a Float and vice-versa?

Tags: java, floating-point, arrays, type-conversion

How do I convert the float value of 12345.12346f to a String of binary values, i.e. "0011010101010101", and vice-versa?

Comment: do you want the representation of this float in memory ? Because float doesn't really have a binary representation, int sure have, but float not.

Comment: Do you just want any reversible conversion, or a sensible (or maybe readable) one?

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure it is what you want, but here's a solution to have the binary representation of the IEEE 754 floating-point "double format" bit layout for a float (it is basically the memory representation of a float) :

```
int intBits = Float.floatToIntBits(yourFloat); 
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(intBits);
```

For the reverse procedure :

```
int intBits = Integer.parseInt(myString, 2);
float myFloat = Float.intBitsToFloat(intBits);
```

Comment: Integer.parseLong doesn't exist

Comment: thanks for the correction :) was from my first try with long instead of int

Comment: Would the result be signed or unsigned? Looking for signed.

Comment: After hours of searching and trying I found your answer. Works as intended. Thanks alot!

Comment: I have almost the same problem as the questioner. I have a communications simulator that genertaes Binary which is 'caught' by a listening process. I start with "float flt = -45732.9287f", and I can see that the Binary received is correct, but the conversion back to Float using this solution throws "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11000111001100101010010011101110" from "java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)"." The Binary generated is clearly a correctly structured IEEE-754 binary32 format, coming from a call to "int revint = Integer.parseInt(str, 2);"

Answer (score 3):

Working sample:

```
class F { 
  public static void main( String ... args ) { 
    System.out.println(
          Integer.toBinaryString( 
             Float.floatToIntBits(12345.12346f)
          ) 
     );
  }
}
```

Output:

```
1000110010000001110010001111110
```

Answer (score 3):

For signed Floats, use Long or BigInteger to parse the string. Casting by int causes the digit at first of 32 bits be intepreted as sign digit.
procedure :

```
int intBits = Float.floatToIntBits(yourFloat); 
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(intBits);
```

reverse procedure :

```
int intBits = new BigInteger(myString, 2).intValue();
// int intBits = (int) Long.parseLong(myString, 2);
float myFloat = Float.intBitsToFloat(intBits);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the bit representation of a Java Float value using

```
Float.floatToIntBits(float f);
```

Once you have done that you can test each bit of the resulting int in turn, starting with the highest, and find out if it set, writing a '1' if it is set and a '0' if not.

Comment: there is a Integer.toBinaryString(intBits) method for retrieving a binary representation in String.