# Adding binary number with decimals

Tags: android, binary

I want to add binary numbers which contain decimals, like this: 11.0101+111.101

Comment: Where is coma? Do you mean decimal?

Comment: I mean the "." by saying coma

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325504/java-convert-floating-point-binary-to-floating-point-decimal

Comment: Also see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number

Comment: Comma is `,`. Decimal is `.`

Comment: thatnks @almasshaikh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a function which will take a `String` containing a number in binary format with a floating point and convert it to `double`. Then you need to use this function on text from two `EditText`s (i presume) and add them together. The result will be a `double`.

Code is in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23325722/2444099